# $f:[0,\infty] \rightarrow \Re$, $f(0)=a= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$, f is infinitely differentiable, Prove that all differentials have roots.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

$$
f:[0,\infty] \rightarrow  \Re 
$$
$$
f(0)=a= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)
$$
f is infinitely differentiable

Prove that all differentials have roots.

My take:
If $f$ is constant, then it's obvious.
Assume that f is rising on $[0,c]$ for some $c$. Then we can find some $c_{1}>a$ and we know, that because $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=a$, that there must be $c_{2}>a$, such that $f(c_{1})=f(c_{2})$. By Rolle theorem we know that there exists $c_{3}\in(c_{1},c_2)$ such that $f'(c_3)=0$.

Ok, so now there are two possibilities. Either there is $c_4>c_3$ such that $f(c_4)=0$ and by Rolle theorem we get $c_5\in(c_3,c_4)$ and $f''(c_5)=0$ or there is no such $c_5$.
If there is no such $c_5$ then for all $x>c_4$, $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$ and it can't be true that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=a$.

If I am right, then I guess that essential part is solved and now I don't know how nicely set up induction out of this.
If I am wrong then I need your help.

Comment: $[0,\infty]\,\,$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\colon D\to\Bbb R$ be a $C^\infty$ function with the following property:

> There exists $b\in D$ such that $[b,\infty)\subseteq D$ and for every $r>0$, the set $f^{-1}\bigl((f(b)-r,f(b)+r\bigr)$ is unbounded.

**Lemma.** Then $f'$ has a root and also has this property

*Proof.* Let $f$ be such a function and pick $b$ as per the property.
If $f$ is constant on $[b,\infty)$, then picking $b'>b$ shows that $f'$ has the property as well.
So assume $f$ is not constant on $[b,\infty)$  and accordingly pick $c>b$ with $f(c)\ne f(b)$. Using the property with $r=\frac12|f(c)-f(b)|$ shows that there exists $x>c$ such that $|f(x)-f(b)|<\frac12|f(c)-f(b)|$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem applied to $[a,c]$ and to $[c,x]$ we find $\xi_1\in(a,c)$ and $\xi_2\in(c,x)$ with $f(\xi_1)=f(\xi_2)=\frac{f(b)+f(c)}2$.
Then using Rolle, we find $b'\in(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ with $f'(b')=0$.
Remains to show that for every $r>0$, the set $f'^{-1}((-r,r))$ is unbounded:
Let $A=f^{-1}((f(b)-1,f(b)+1))$. By assumption, $A$ is unbounded. 
Let $r>0$ and $x_0\in\Bbb R$ be given
We want to show that there exists $\xi>x_0$ with $|f'(x)|<r$.
Pick $x_1\in A$ with $x_1>x_0$. Pick $x_2\in A$ with $x_2>x_1+\frac 2r$.
Then $2>|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|=|x_2-x_1|\cdot |f'(\xi)|$ for some $\xi$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$, hence $|f'(\xi)|<r$ as desired. $\square$

Let $P(n)$ be the following claim:

> If $f$ has the property described above, then  each of the derivatives $f',f'',\ldots, f^{(n)}$ has at least one root.

The lemma tells us that $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$. It also immediately gives us $P(1)$. We conclude:

> If $f$ has the property above, then each of its derivatives has a root.

Finally, note that the given limit condition on your $f$ implies the property above.